# Should [tips] also be tagged with the challenge type?

Tags: discussion, policy, tags

We've got 93 [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions. 61 of those also have the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag. I suspect that actually all 93 of them (or at least 90) are actually tips for code golfing. So this seems like fairly inconsistent tagging practice, and I can see why there's confusion about it. It would be nice to decide how to use tags together with [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips).

The main arguments *for* including [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is that tips could in principle be about other challenge types. So it would be good to see from the tags what kind of help the question is actually asking for.

The main argument *against* including [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is that it is intended to indicate a challenge with a fixed winning criterion and so non-challenge posts shouldn't get the tag.

I *think* I am personally in favour of starting to consistently include the tag, and hence make challenge-type tags also mandatory for [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question, but I'd be very interested in further arguments for and against including it, as well as the general community opinion.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing tips questions for `king-of-the-hill` and `fastest-code`.

Comment: I'm torn on how to tag them though. People who follow those tags might be interested in seeing the tips questions or they might not. Half of me wants to give them the choice with `king-of-the-hill-tips` and `fastest-code-tips` but I don't think we have enough tips questions to justify more than one `tips` tag.

Comment: @trichoplax You can also ignore tags or exclude them when searching, so getting rid of them if you *only* want challenges is not a big problem. The thing is that fastest code tips likely belong elsewhere (CR, SO, maybe Math.SE). For KotHs I'm less sure, but at the same time I sort of doubt there are tips that *are* generally applicable. With the current challenge types it's hard to see where else tips would fit, but that isn't to say that it will always remain like that with whatever future challenge types we come up with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes

[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) should be tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or whatever contest type they relate to. This will make it clear that not all tips are necessarily about code golf.

I don't think we need to bother creating a bunch of new tags like [king-of-the-hill-tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill-tips) because we don't get that many [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions to begin with, so there is not a huge need to be able to subscribe to specific tip types. (And I honestly don't think we will ever be so overrun with new tips questions that this will be necessary.)

If someone *really* wants to find koth tips questions they can always just search.

Comment: Additionally, often there can be assigned a clear winner in this sort question (I'm not arguing that it should be done, but rather that it could be done): the answer that golfed it down to the least characters wins.

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs This should also apply to tips lists. In an advice-type tips question I might accept the most comprehensive answer, or the one with the most helpful explanation (or generally applicable strategies) as opposed to the one that squeezed out the very last byte.