# Should we clean-up our code-golf-related [tips] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Here is a search for these.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips+-code-golf) (currently <s>42</s> 7 of them, but some are things like "Tips for making Polyglots" and thus don't need the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag.

[Here is a search for all tips questions that don't have a scoring criterion.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips+-king-of-the-hill+-code-golf+-atomic-code-golf+-code-bowling)

[The consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/46271) is that [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions should be tagged with the applicable challenge type, i.e. fastest-code, code-golf, etc.

Should we go through and add the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag to the 30-some questions that need it?

(I'm not arguing they should be tagged as such, I'm saying we should make a clean-up effort and add that tag)

[This not a dupe.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/should-tips-also-be-tagged-with-the-challenge-type)

---

This has been done.  7 questions remain that don't have [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) as a tag, 5 of which are closed.  Of these, one of the open ones is [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf), and the other open question is [Tips for creating polyglots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101159/tips-for-creating-polyglots) and doesn't need any scoring tags.

Of the closed ones:

- [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59997/how-can-pyth-be-improved) fall [under](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60312/how-could-stringy-be-improved) "issue tracker" catagory and [thus are off-topic.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/can-i-ask-a-question-seeking-feature-requests-for-a-golfing-language)
- [Best place for learning GolfScript?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52024/best-place-for-learning-golfscript) is a recommendation question, off-topic.
- [Tips for King of the Hill bots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77117/tips-for-king-of-the-hill-bots) is closed as too broad.
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110631/data-structure-for-time-constraint-and-memory-constraint is a recommendation/SO-type question.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9790/the-tips-tag-is-currently-golf-focused-can-this-be-made-explicit-one-way-or-the).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should \[tips\] also be tagged with the challenge type?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/should-tips-also-be-tagged-with-the-challenge-type)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem sorry, to clarify: I mean to organize/propose a tag cleanup, where we tag every applicable [tips] question with [code-golf].

Comment: Good point, I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that the [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/34718) is to add the tag of the challenge type to the tips question, I think it'd be a good idea to update existing tips questions.

In order to avoid bumping them all at once, this should be done gradually.

Though it's in the question, here it is again:

[A List of Tips Questions not Tagged with [code-golf]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips+-code-golf)